# Create a *read-only* CSV

Tags: r, readr

I hope this is a straightforward question -- I create a lot of output files using `write_csv`, and for auditing purposes, I need to be sure that those csv files can't be modified by someone else. Is there a way to write a CSV file that's read-only? `write.csv` and `write_csv` don't have any obvious parameters for this when creating the file; am I missing anything, or is there another way to do this?

Comment: I don't believe so. The `openxlsx` package however has the function `protectWorkbook()` to password-protect the modification of xlsx files.

Comment: Write the files to a read-only medium, e.g. a write-once DVD. There is effectively no other way (short of a cryptographically signed ledger, which opens a huge can of worms, isn’t practical, and *certainly* isn’t a CSV). This isn’t specific to R: what you want is *fundamentally* hard/impossible. Since you mention auditing: how do you ensure read-only access for auditing purposes in other contexts? Does your company have a process for this, i.e. via a database interface? If so, use that.

Comment: Protection of a file is an OS-level thing. A generic CSV-writer function/program only writes to a file, where the owner/group/permissions of that file are subjected to sane defaults (defined in the OS or in the user's current shell). To make a file read-only also depends on the filesystem itself; for instance, linux-like filesystems would use `chmod` or similar, whereas NTFS, NFS, CIFS, etc are all different. Further, your comment about "auditing" suggests this really should be handled elsewhere.

Comment: If you have a web-presence available (for the users that need these files), then you can make the CSV files available for download. This ensures that they have easy access, and lacking security problems with the web-server, it ensures that the source files on the web page are unchanged. (I'm assuming that "they" have no control over the webpage listing these files.)

Comment: If you have a github/gitlab (or other git-based) instance available, set up a repo and commit the files. You have control over who can commit to that repo. You have a complete log of what changes were done to files, when, and by whom. And all of this can be further enhanced with attributability using gpg signatures on the files. It's a bit of overhead, but again your notion of security and auditing demands some overhead on your part. at least.

Comment: Last option (which to me is still not as good as a git repo) would be something like nextcloud, if you or your company has it. This allows you to upload a file and share it with individuals, with groups, or as a shared-link, and all of these options have various controls over the files' readonly state.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use this:

```
system("attrib +R file.csv")
```

Comment: `attrib` settings can be trivially undone. This is insufficient for auditing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).